# Handle html special character with MvcHtmlString

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I have a string [<PB] and need it to be displayed as it is. I convert it to `new MvcHtmlString("[&lt;PB]")` and write into html. But when it displays in the browser it shows [ only.

So I change the string to [&ltPB] or [&lt;PB], but `new MvcHtmlString()` change it to `[&ampltPB]` or `[&amp;amplt;PB]` respectively, and the browser displays it as `[&ltPB]` or `[&amp;lt;PB]`.

How to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: `Html.Raw()` might work.

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

call ToHtmlString method in your cshtml file

```
@(new MvcHtmlString("[<PB]").ToHtmlString())
```

Comment: please make fiddle where it doesnt work. for example here https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sdtkm1 its works